# Big arabic permalinks not work

Tags: permalinks

I have error in permalink, I have post that title is big like :-

```
مراجعة : Sony Xperia Z2 و إيجابياته و سلبياته و كل ما تريد معرفته عن الجهاز !
```

Now when open the post in my site i see permalink like :-

```
www.domain.com/مراجعة-sony-xperia-z2-و-إيجابياته-و-سلبياته-و-كل-ما
```

**Its read only 11 word**

But i set the permalink structure is /%postname%/.

Why its not get all post title ?

**update:-**

I search and see this code that solved my problem :-

```
// first of all lets remove standard hook
remove_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes' );

// add our custom hook 
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'wpse8170_sanitize_title_with_dashes', 10, 3 );
function wpse8170_sanitize_title_with_dashes( $title, $raw_title = '', $context = 'display' ) {
    $title = strip_tags($title);
    // Preserve escaped octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
    // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
    $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
    // Restore octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

    if (seems_utf8($title)) {
        if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
            $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 1000); // <--- here is the trick!
    }

    $title = strtolower($title);
    $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
    $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);

    if ( 'save' == $context ) {
        // Convert nbsp, ndash and mdash to hyphens
        $title = str_replace( array( '%c2%a0', '%e2%80%93', '%e2%80%94' ), '-', $title );

            // Strip these characters entirely
            $title = str_replace( array(
            // iexcl and iquest
            '%c2%a1', '%c2%bf',
            // angle quotes
            '%c2%ab', '%c2%bb', '%e2%80%b9', '%e2%80%ba',
            // curly quotes
            '%e2%80%98', '%e2%80%99', '%e2%80%9c', '%e2%80%9d',
            '%e2%80%9a', '%e2%80%9b', '%e2%80%9e', '%e2%80%9f',
            // copy, reg, deg, hellip and trade
            '%c2%a9', '%c2%ae', '%c2%b0', '%e2%80%a6', '%e2%84%a2',
            // grave accent, acute accent, macron, caron
            '%cc%80', '%cc%81', '%cc%84', '%cc%8c',
        ), '', $title );

        // Convert times to x
        $title = str_replace( '%c3%97', 'x', $title );
    }

    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
    $title = trim($title, '-');

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: You said *"arabic permalinks"* but you posted a Roman. Confused to gasp the question.

Comment: Have you tried with more than one? Are they all cut off at the same length (only the `%postname%` part, not the domain)? And if yes. What is the length?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam i edit my post

Comment: @kaiser i use in wp-admin %postname%

Comment: Ok, please read my last comment again and answer those questions. With an [edit], please.

Comment: @kaiser read my edit post its read only 200 char

Comment: _"Are they [your titles] all cut off at the same length?"_ ... was my question. There is no [edit] to your question if that is true or not. You still didn't tell the length where the title is cut off. And there is no edit stating something with 200 chars. That was the suggestion from @sakibmoon in his/her answer

Comment: I am sure edt my post, Its read only 11 word

Comment: @Kaiser is telling you to do some more tests with different titles. Also mention after how many characters/letters(not word) the URL's get cut with each title.

Comment: @The15Seconds Please add your solution not in the question, but as an answer, and accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark so that some other will be benefited. :) And, don't forget to mention the source, from where you got the code. :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what encoding you are using. If you look at the database structure of [wp_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts), you will see that `post_name` field is `varchar(200)`

So, at most it can store 200 bytes of data. If you are using `UTF-16` encoding, it needs 4 bytes to store an Arabic character. So, at most it can store 50 Arabic characters.

For different encoding, it will be different. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322191/how-many-bytes-do-we-need-to-store-an-arabic-character

Comment: Thank, I set the `post_name` like as `post_title` and nothing new. what can i do ??